# Passing a struct from application to class library

Tags: c#

I have a class library that contains an API function that will handle all the processing, My application has a struct and few methods that will be passed in to the API function. How can I pass a struct from my application to .dll?

In my application:

```
private void IFaceConn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Interface.RegisterInterface(iface, ref cfg, ConnectFn, DisconnectFn);
    }
```

In my .dll:

```
public void RegisterInterface(Enum iface, "struct goes here"  Func<int> connect, Func<int> disconnect)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking what the struct parameter declaration should look like:

```
public void RegisterInterface(Enum iface, ref StructType structType, Func<int> connect, Func<int> disconnect)
{
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie, when I type StructType i get an error saying "the type or namespace StructType could not be found".

Comment: @Art - By `StructType` I mean what ever the type of `cfg` is.

Comment: +1. @Art"StructType" as placeholder for whatever type of your `cfg` is.

Comment: I don't have access to that struct because it resides in the application not .dll.

Comment: @Art - Well you can't reference a type in an assembly you aren't referencing, so you'll have to move it, either to your dll or another assembly which can be referenced by both your library and application.